# Dependency-walker reports errors in HelloWorld

Tags: c++, dependency-walker

to get familiar with dependency-walker I built a simple (32-Bit) command line c++ HelloWorld.exe with Visual Studio.

Using (32-Bit) dependency walker on that .exe file it shows me VCRUNTIME140.DLL as a dependency which is fine. But it shows five yellow subnodes for missing dlls in the treeview on the left under the VCRUNTIME140.DLL:

- API-MS-WIN-CRT-RUNTIME-L1-1-0.DLL
- API-MS-WIN-CRT-MATH-L1-1-0.DLL
- API-MS-WIN-CRT-STDIO-L1-1-0.DLL
- API-MS-WIN-CRT-LOCALE-L1-1-0.DLL
- API-MS-WIN-CRT-HEAP-L1-1-0.DLL

Then it shows dozens of errors in the list on the bottom saying "Error opening file. System couldn't find the file". Let me just name 2 here:

- API-MS-WIN-CORE-APIQUERY-L1-1-0.DLL
- API-MS-WIN-CORE-APPCOMPAT-L1-1-1.DLL

The executable is running fine. My question: How do I know which errors to ignore - or shouldn't I ignore them at all?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dependency Walker: missing dlls](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36240215/dependency-walker-missing-dlls)

Comment: Looks like DW is getting a bit long in the tooth and gives false positives.

See: [https://ofekshilon.com/2016/03/27/on-api-ms-win-xxxxx-dll-and-other-dependency-walker-glitches/][1]


  [1]: https://ofekshilon.com/2016/03/27/on-api-ms-win-xxxxx-dll-and-other-dependency-walker-glitches/