# Python scipy module import error due to missing ._ufuncs dll

Tags: python, dll, import, scipy

I have some troubles with sub-module integrate from scipy in python.
I have a 64 bits architecture, and it seems, according to the first lines of the python interpreter (see below) that I am also using a 64 bit build of Python together with Anaconda.

Below is the problem (I just wrote the minimal code to show what's happening)

---

```
Python 3.4.3 |Anaconda 2.3.0 (64-bit)| (default, Mar  6 2015, 12:06:10) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import scipy
>>> import scipy.integrate
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\*********\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\__init__.py", line 55, in <module>
    from .quadrature import *
  File "C:\Users\*********\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\quadrature.py", line 10, in <module>
    from scipy.special.orthogonal import p_roots
  File "C:\Users\*********\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\special\__init__.py", line 636, in <module>
    from ._ufuncs import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: Le module spécifié est introuvable.
```

---

The same happens with import scipy.special

As you can see scipy can be imported, however scipy.integrate generates an error. What is odd is that in the folder
...\lib\site-packages\scipy\special, the ._ufuncs.pyd is appears.
Also, I am using scipty regularly for other purposes, and everythings works usually fine.

I am using version 0.18.0 of scipy and pip 1.8.1. 
I tried to reinstall scipy with conda but this does not seem to change anything.

It seems that the dll cannot be found. I found a few posts on the internet (including one that advises to download a "libmmd.dll" in C:\Windows\SysWOW64) with similar issue, but none seems to work.  My guess is that this is still a pb of 32-64 bit compatibility  as this is the most common pb with python and I remembered having huge pb when first seting up everything a few months ago.

So, following up the initial question, is there a way to know which version (32 bit or 64 bit) of each package or dll is effectively installed/loaded? 
Do you have another idea why I get this error message?

Thank you for your answers, this problem is quite frustrating...

Answer (score 21):

If you use conda and don't want to install MKL and copy the DLLs as mentioned above, I figured out you can fix this by reinstalling icc_rt package:

```
conda remove icc_rt --force
conda install icc_rt --no-deps
```

The `icc_rt` package has the required DLLs (`LIBIFCOREMD.DLL` and `LIBMMD.DLL`).

Below is how I investigated this issue:

I encountered the issue after upgrading my Anaconda to latest version using:

```
conda update conda
conda update anaconda
```

I ran [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) while doing `import scipy.special` to trace which DLL it's trying to load and found out it's `libifcoremd.dll`.
[image: ProcMon Trace]

I then searched my conda pkg cache folder (`~/AppData/Local/Continuum/Anaconda3`) to find out which package carries this DLL

```
$ find . -name '*ifcoremd.*'
./pkgs/icc_rt-2017.0.4-h97af966_0/Library/bin/libifcoremd.dll
./pkgs/mkl-11.3.3-1/Library/bin/libifcoremd.dll
./pkgs/mkl-2017.0.1-0/Library/bin/libifcoremd.dll
./pkgs/mkl-2017.0.3-0/Library/bin/libifcoremd.dll
```

So it's in both `mkl` and `icc_rt` packages. But it looks like the latest anaconda (5.2.0) shipped a more recent version of `mkl` which apparently doesn't have the DLLs anymore:

```
$ conda list|egrep '^(mkl|icc_rt)\s'
icc_rt                    2017.0.4             h97af966_0
mkl                       2018.0.2                      1
```

So presumably when conda upgraded my `mkl`, it deleted the DLLs from my `Library\bin` folder. So by force reinstalling `icc_rt`, I got the DLLs back.

Comment: Upvote +1000.  Can't say this enough ... LIFE SAVER!  Thank you; been bashing my head for two days.  Using Process Monitor was brilliant.  Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Just works! I would have reinstalled anaconda if I didn't find this answer.

Answer (score 2):

I solved by the following steps:

1. Install [MKL](https://registrationcenter.intel.com/en/products/download/3055/).
2. And for my situation, I checked `\scipy\special\_ufuncs.cp36-win_amd64.pyd` using [Dependency Wakler](http://www.dependencywalker.com/). Found I miss `LIBIFCOREMD.DLL` and `LIBMMD.DLL`. I solved this by install [Intel Distribution for Python](https://software.intel.com/en-us/distribution-for-python). Intel Distribution for Python is actually a special version of Python 3.5. And it includes lots of DLL needed. After installing Intel Distribution for Python, go to `path_to_Intel_Distribution_for_Python\Library\bin`(on my computer is `C:\IntelPython3\Library\bin`), and copy all folder and files to `path_to_your_default_python\Library\bin`(on my computer is `C:\Anaconda3\Library\bin`). 
   [image: capture]
   (ignore other missing dlls according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40077240/4956987)).

Then problem solved.

PS. Maybe sometimes files in `path_to_Intel_Distribution_for_Python\Library\include\` are also needed?

PPS. You can uninstall Intel Distribution for Python if you no longer need it.

PPPS. A more simple way is to use the wheel. [Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/). but I like to use `conda update --all` to update packages... then everything messed up...

Comment: This solved the problem for me (Windows 10 and Anaconda 3 with Python 3.5.2). Did not try the 'conda update --all' part. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It appears the DLL load failed because the module specified is irretrievable?

Please see:

[ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application. But the DLL's are there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19019720/importerror-dll-load-failed-1-is-not-a-valid-win32-application-but-the-dlls)

Comment: please share the answer, and then keep this link as a reference.