# Parcel Error - module not found @parcel\fs-search\fs-search.win32-x64-msvc.node

Tags: javascript, node.js, compiler-errors, parceljs, windows-11

I recently updated my windows from windows 10 to 11.

** Update ** I've reinstalled windows 10 again, but I'm receiving the same error

When I rund yarn start, or npm start, I receive the below error

```
λ yarn start
yarn run v1.22.15
$ parcel index.html
Error: The specified module could not be found.
\\?\C:\Users\Ammar Home\Desktop\testing\node_modules\@parcel\fs-search\fs-search.win32-x64-msvc.node
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1144:18)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)
    at require (C:\Users\Ammar Home\Desktop\testing\node_modules\v8-compile-cache\v8-compile-cache.js:159:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Ammar Home\Desktop\testing\node_modules\@parcel\fs-search\index.js:19:20)
    at Module._compile (C:\Users\Ammar Home\Desktop\testing\node_modules\v8-compile-cache\v8-compile-cache.js:192:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:12) {
  code: 'ERR_DLOPEN_FAILED'
}
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

my setup is very simple, here're the details

**package.json file**

```
{
  "name": "testing",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "parcel index.html",
    "build": "parcel build"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "parcel": "^2.0.0"
  }
}
```

nothing special in my index.html or my javascript file,

**html file**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

  <script src="./index.js" type="module"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**javascript file**

```
console.log("Hello world");
```

**my Environment**

```
Parcel  2
Node    v14.18.1
npm/Yarn    
Operating System    Windows 11 Pro
Version 21H2
OS build 22000.258
experience Windows Feature Experience Pack 1000.22000.258.0
```

**labtop specification**

```
Processor   Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-8250U CPU @ 1.60GHz   1.80 GHz
Installed RAM   8.00 GB (7.88 GB usable)
System type 64-bit operating system, x64-based processor
```

The wierd thing is when I looked at the specified folder in the error, I found that module "fs-search.win32-x64-msvc.node" , It's already there under following directory

node_moduels/@parcel/fs-search /fs-search.win32-x64-msvc.node

It's already exist, however the error claiming it's not found!

I've removed node_modules, several times and reinstalled parcel again, however the same error accrud,
I'm not sure what could be causing this issue,
any one can help?

**Debug log**

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'start'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.15
3 info using node@v14.18.1
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle testing@1.0.0~prestart: testing@1.0.0
6 info lifecycle testing@1.0.0~start: testing@1.0.0
7 verbose lifecycle testing@1.0.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle testing@1.0.0~start: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\Users\Ammar Home\Desktop\testing\node_modules\.bin;C:\Users\Ammar Home\cmder\vendor\conemu-maximus5\ConEmu\Scripts;C:\Users\Ammar Home\cmder\vendor\conemu-maximus5;C:\Users\Ammar Home\cmder\vendor\conemu-maximus5\ConEmu;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\Ammar Home\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\Ammar Home\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\Ammar Home\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Users\Ammar Home\cmder\vendor\bin;C:\Users\Ammar Home\cmder
9 verbose lifecycle testing@1.0.0~start: CWD: C:\Users\Ammar Home\Desktop\testing
10 silly lifecycle testing@1.0.0~start: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'parcel index.html' ]
11 silly lifecycle testing@1.0.0~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle testing@1.0.0~start: Failed to exec start script
13 verbose stack Error: testing@1.0.0 start: `parcel index.html`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:400:28)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:400:28)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1058:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:293:5)
14 verbose pkgid testing@1.0.0
15 verbose cwd C:\Users\Ammar Home\Desktop\testing
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.22000
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
18 verbose node v14.18.1
19 verbose npm  v6.14.15
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error testing@1.0.0 start: `parcel index.html`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the testing@1.0.0 start script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue caused due to missing library on the computer.
fs-search requires Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable (x64).

You can get the download here -> https://aka.ms/vs/17/release/vc_redist.x64.exe

I've got the answer from github issues on parcel

https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/issues/7104

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce this on my end with the same node and win10 versions. However, according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41272553/4739687) (about an unreladed package) the "module could not be found" error can occur when the native module file (which does exist) tries to load a dependency that's not present on the system. You could try using [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to check the dependencies of `node_moduels/@parcel/fs-search/fs-search.win32-x64-msvc.node` on your machine and see if they are all installed.

Answer (score 0):

install the parcel-bundler.It will solve your problem

//use command
npm install -D parcel-bundler

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).