# Deploying Qt (C++/QML) application on Windows

Tags: windows, qt, qml

I started a Qt project with only C++ code in it, everything worked fine at this point. Here are my configuration and the steps I'm following to deploy my executable :

Programming on Windows10 64bits, x64 processor, Lenovo Thinkpad Tablet. Using Qt5.9 framework and MinGW32bit compiler.

- (1) I first build the project and launch `windeployqt.exe` on a copy of my build directory.
- (2) Then, I put every DLLs plus the executable into a Wix project to make a `MSI` package. As far as I know, the output of this `MSI` setup should do no more than just copying the files into the `ProgramFiles` directory, and adding the correct shortcuts to start menu and desktop.

At this point, everything always worked. But since a few days now, QML code was added to the project (therefore some OpenGL dependant plugins). I added a `QQuickWidget` which instantiates a QML geographical Map object on my viewport. After I managed to get it to work on Windows, I am no more able to get a *stand-alone* * executable. Running it with Qt IDE works but, but running the *stand-alone* * executable does not. (Sorry if the terms are not correct: *stand-alone* with DLLs and lot of files dependancies)

When all the DLLs are copied into the executable folder, (step 1. above) the application get stuck in background, and shows nothing. Also there is no runtime error to debug it or to find out the missing DLLs, if there are.

My thoughts are that some QML plugins are not loaded, or something went wrong with OpenGLES and Angle, here are some of the DLLs I get as dependancies :

- `D3Dcompiler_47.dll` `libEGL.dll` `libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll` `libGLESV2.dll` `libstdc++-6.dll` `opengl32sw.dll` `Qt5Core.dll` `Qt5Gui.dll` `Qt5Network.dll` `Qt5Positioning.dll` `Qt5Qml.dll` `Qt5Quick.dll` `Qt5QuickWidgets.dll` `Qt5SerialPort.dll` `Qt5Svg.dll` `Qt5Widgets.dll` at the same level of the executable.
- `qwindows.dll` into a "platforms" folder, and some other folders such as "qmltooling", "position", "platforminputcontexts" ... (**EDIT** and seemingly the relevant QML plugins directories).

I don't know what it could be. Has anyone any idea ?

---

The output when setting the environment variable QML_IMPORT_TRACE to 1. The `qt.network.ssl ...` messages are not part of the qml trace. I always got them since I added the QML map but it seems not to be a problem when running via Qt Creator.

```
QQmlImportDatabase::addImportPath: "C:/Qt/5.9/mingw53_32/qml"
QQmlImportDatabase::addImportPath: "qrc:/qt-project.org/imports"
QQmlImportDatabase::addImportPath: "C:/Users/hermes/Documents/build-MyApplication-Desktop_Qt_5_9_0_MinGW_32bit-Release/src/release"
QQmlImportDatabase::addImportPath: "C:/Qt/5.9/mingw53_32/qml"
QQmlImportDatabase::addImportPath: "qrc:/qt-project.org/imports"
QQmlImportDatabase::addImportPath: "C:/Users/hermes/Documents/build-MyApplication-Desktop_Qt_5_9_0_MinGW_32bit-Release/src/release"
QQmlImports(qrc:/qml.qrc/main.qml)::addLibraryImport: "QtQuick" 2.0 as ""
QQmlImports(qrc:/qml.qrc/main.qml)::importExtension: loaded "C:/Qt/5.9/mingw53_32/qml/QtQuick.2/qmldir"
QQmlImportDatabase::registerPluginTypes: "QtQuick" from "C:/Qt/5.9/mingw53_32/qml/QtQuick.2"
QQmlImports(qrc:/qml.qrc/main.qml)::addLibraryImport: "QtQuick.Controls" 1.4 as ""
QQmlImports(qrc:/qml.qrc/main.qml)::importExtension: loaded "C:/Qt/5.9/mingw53_32/qml/QtQuick/Controls/qmldir"
QQmlImportDatabase::registerPluginTypes: "QtQuick.Controls" from "C:/Qt/5.9/mingw53_32/qml/QtQuick/Controls"
QQmlImports(qrc:/qml.qrc/main.qml)::addLibraryImport: "QtLocation" 5.9 as ""
QQmlImports(qrc:/qml.qrc/main.qml)::importExtension: loaded "C:/Qt/5.9/mingw53_32/qml/QtLocation/qmldir"
QQmlImportDatabase::registerPluginTypes: "QtLocation" from "C:/Qt/5.9/mingw53_32/qml/QtLocation"
QQmlImports(qrc:/qml.qrc/main.qml)::addLibraryImport: "QtPositioning" 5.5 as ""
QQmlImports(qrc:/qml.qrc/main.qml)::importExtension: loaded "C:/Qt/5.9/mingw53_32/qml/QtPositioning/qmldir"
QQmlImportDatabase::registerPluginTypes: "QtPositioning" from "C:/Qt/5.9/mingw53_32/qml/QtPositioning"
QQmlImports(qrc:/qml.qrc/main.qml)::resolveType: "PluginParameter" => "QDeclarativeGeoServiceProviderParameter" TYPE
QQmlImports(qrc:/qml.qrc/main.qml)::resolveType: "MapQuickItem" => "QDeclarativeGeoMapQuickItem" TYPE
QQmlImports(qrc:/qml.qrc/main.qml)::resolveType: "Image" => "QQuickImage" TYPE
QQmlImports(qrc:/qml.qrc/main.qml)::resolveType: "Rotation" => "QQuickRotation" TYPE
QQmlImports(qrc:/qml.qrc/main.qml)::resolveType: "Map" => "QDeclarativeGeoMap" TYPE
QQmlImports(qrc:/qml.qrc/main.qml)::resolveType: "Plugin" => "QDeclarativeGeoServiceProvider" TYPE
QQmlImports(qrc:/qml.qrc/main.qml)::resolveType: "Connections" => "QQmlConnections" TYPE
QQmlImports(qrc:/qml.qrc/main.qml)::resolveType: "Component" => "QQmlComponent" TYPE
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve TLSv1_1_client_method
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve TLSv1_2_client_method
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve TLSv1_1_server_method
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve TLSv1_2_server_method
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSL_select_next_proto
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSL_CTX_set_next_proto_select_cb
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSL_get0_next_proto_negotiated
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSL_set_alpn_protos
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSL_CTX_set_alpn_select_cb
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSL_get0_alpn_selected
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSL_get0_next_proto_negotiated
mincore\com\oleaut32\dispatch\ups.cpp(2128)\OLEAUT32.dll!74865072: (caller: 7486FE4F) ReturnHr(1) tid(2e20) 8002801D Bibliothèque non inscrite.
mincore\com\oleaut32\dispatch\ups.cpp(2128)\OLEAUT32.dll!74865072: (caller: 7486FE4F) ReturnHr(2) tid(2e20) 8002801D Bibliothèque non inscrite.
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSL_get0_next_proto_negotiated
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSL_get0_next_proto_negotiated
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSL_get0_next_proto_negotiated
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSL_get0_next_proto_negotiated
```

Comment: Try running the application with `QML_IMPORT_TRACE=1` and provide the output here.

Comment: @herme5 Did you use the `--qmldir` option of windeployqt ? And did you deploy all the folders generated by `windeployqt` (including those created when using `--qmldir`) ?

Comment: @BenjaminT. I tried the c++ command `QCoreApplication::addLibraryPath("C:/path/to/plugins")` instead. I always shipped all the folders generated by `windeployqt` but never tried `--qmldir`. I will get a look at this.

Comment: @Mitch I edited the Question, and added the output

Comment: I had this problem last week with 5.9 on Windows 7. windeploy-qt misses a few important files. I'll check tomorrow which files it was and get back to you

Comment: @MarkCh Thank you, any help will be very appreciated. @BenjaminT I tried the `--qmldir` `<path to my qml files>`, had a lot of new missing files (especially for my QML plugins), but it is at the same point, the executable runs without error, but is stuck as a background process, the window is not showing.

Comment: I had similar problems and could resolve them with Dependency Walker. I loaded the exe and started profiling. After some time, it told me which QML files it couldn't load - just added them to the respective folders in my install package

Comment: @king_nak I tried running Dependency Walker , and it did not reports anything but API-MS-WIN missing dependency. But according to [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36240215/dependency-walker-missing-dlls) it can be ignored as long as Windows resolves these dynamically (If i understand well).

Comment: You have to start profiling (Menu > Profile > Start Profiling). That starts the program and makes an extensive log for all DLLs, Symbols, etc. I got errors like `QQmlApplicationEngine failed to load component
qrc:/main.qml:3 module "QtQuick.Controls.Styles" is not installed` before copying the required QMLs to the application dir

Comment: @king_nak thank you very much, I didn't know about this feature. Just tried this and everything seemed okay until Dependency Walker got frozen, the last message is `Loaded IMM32.DLL [...] Successfully hooked module`. I did not see any Qml plugin loading failure nor Qt plugins. Nevertheless, do you ship your QML code with the DLLs and the executable ?

Comment: I just copy them with the program, like depicted in Marc Ch's answer below... Haven't found a better way yet

Answer (score 3):

for QML applications you should follow the below command while using windeploy.exe

> windeployqt --qmldir [path-to-app-qml-files] [path-to-app-binary]

Answer (score 0):

copy from the Qt install folder to your .exe folder:

- bin\Qt5QuickControls2.dll
- bin\Qt5QuickTemplates2.dll
- qml\QtQuick
- qml\QtQuick.2

so that your .exe folder looks like this:

[image]

If the program now runs ok, then you can go into the QtQuick folder and try to remove the libraries which you are not using in your program.

Comment: good luck. If this is not enough, try copying the entire contents of [qt_install_dir]\qml into your .exe folder, and then prune it down by trial and error.

Comment: I tried this, and I'm sorry to tell you it has no effects. I began adding the files of yours which are not among mines: only `Qt5DBus.dll` at all. By the way `scenegraph` folder is not available with MinGW (?!). Then I copied all the contents of `qml` folder, and then all the contents of the `plugins` folder, and then all the "core" DLLs (those which are in the same folder than Qt5***.dll and libGL and D3DCompiler ...). Obviously each times I gave it a try, I paid attention to kill my application process.

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that, in that case I am unfortunately not able to help. Shall i delete my answer?

Comment: I think I'm gonna try to compile it with MSVC. By the way, I've seen several forum where `windeployqt` is said to be buggy and does not copy all the required files, don't know if your post can help somebody else. Feel free to delete it or not but thank you anyway !

Comment: yes, I have been using MSVC. FYI I tried deleting scenegraph folder, and my application still runs OK.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the useful [windeployqt](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-deployment.html) tool which gather all needed dependencies together inside release directory:

```
rem %1 H:\src\trunk\src\qt\cargofinder
pushd f:\qt\5.9\msvc2015_64\bin
call qtenv2.bat
popd
windeployqt --qmldir %1 .
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'm using `windeployqt.exe` with a git bash unix-like terminal. So excuse my ignorance but what are you doing with the command lines you wrote ? I'm not comfortable with Windows shell, nor scripting in with batch files.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem recently, I am using the compiler **cl(MSVC2017)**, the **QT version 5.12 64bit**.I describe the process I solved as following:

1. I copy all program dependent Dlls depends.exe hints. But when I double click the exe, nothing happened even appeared in the **Task Mannager** program.
2. Then I learned about monitoring Dlls dependent by the **Process Explorer**, I find out some others dependent dlls like **Qt5Quick**, **Qt5QuickTemplates2.dll**, *Qt5QuickControls2.dll**, etc. and many Dlls in **msvc2017_64\qml** folder.
3. I also used charts, so I cannot forget **Qt5Charts.dll**.

Okay, so far it works. So many Dlls dependent from Qt, I worn out.Tips: Copy qml floder to runtime directory, and then run the exe, then fell all other 
unoccupied files heartily.(ps:seemly cannot delete some unoccupied thing in qml\QtQuick, if I delete it double click the exe will have nothing happened.)

Comment: Why didn't you use the `windeployqt` tool? Or did you have a problem with it, which forced you to do this work by hand yourself?