# Invalid file, specified module not found

Tags: matlab, file, mex

I received this error after I was able to successfully install the "uhdinterface.mexw64" MEX file. Apparently the MEX file is invalid. After I check the dependencies according to [this](https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/95906-how-do-i-profile-my-exe-or-dll-file-with-dependency-walker) and then I notice that hundreds of dependencies are missing. I cannot possibly download and install each of these. What can be a alternative?

I have MATLAB R2013b, SDK 7.1 compiler and Microsoft Visual Studio 8 and 2010.

Comment: Can you specify what your error is? Can you please show some work?

Comment: @SreejithMenon Yes. Error: At least one required implicit or forwarded dependency was not found.
Error: At least one module has an unresolved import due to a missing export function in an implicitly dependent module.
Error: Modules with different CPU types were found.
Error: A circular dependency was detected.
Warning: At least one delay-load dependency module was not found.
Warning: At least one module has an unresolved import due to a missing export function in a delay-load dependent module..

Comment: According to  Dependance Walker software,  Most of the dependancies are of the type "API-MS-WIN-CORE-CONSOLE-L1-2-0.DLL".... and 100's of more. I cannot physically find all and install them can i? There has to be one huge file which i may have how to download and install, one which contains all missing libraries or whatever??

Comment: [Most likely these API..-dls are not related to your problem.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36240215/dependency-walker-missing-dlls)

Comment: @ventiseis  Ok. But then if i run the MEX file, i still get the same error. All other dependancies are fixed.

Comment: I still don't understand. Did you compile that file on your machine and install or did you just download it? Did you follow (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nav-ei-tum/uhdinterface/master/INSTALL)?

Comment: Yes i compiled it on my machine and installed the MEX file called "uhdinterface.mexw64" . But when i right click this file and say run, i get that above error.

Comment: Any more solutions?