# Dependency Walker: errors were detected when processing

Tags: c++, dll, compilation

I succesfully compiled my `.cpp` file and later generated `.dll` file from that `.cpp` file (very simple code).  When I run **Dependency Walker** on `.dll` file, I get following error:

[image]

What does this error mean and how to solve it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dependency Walker: missing dlls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36240215/dependency-walker-missing-dlls)

Comment: @dxiv, I already checked that link and I don't think that's the answer for my question :)

Comment: It *is* the same question with the same answer - Dependency Walker doesn't understand [API sets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/apiindex/windows-apisets).

Comment: @dxiv thanks! I read it again. So, I should just ignore those errors?

Comment: That's your judgment call. If you run it on Win7, for example, without the UCRT installed you'll see pretty much the same errors, but in that case they *would* be warranted. Dependency Walker is (unfortunately) outdated, and [lucasg's Dependencies](https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies/issues) can still be rough around the edges, but at least it's under active development.