# Can't find `DllExported` method in custom DLL, says System.EntryPointNotFoundException: 'Unable to find an entry point named 'xyz' in DLL 'abc.dll'.'

Tags: c#, .net, dll

I'm trying to create a small `.dll` which will be able to cancel process by sending *CTRL+C* signal to that process.

And I'm exporting my function like this:

```
        [DllExport("StopProgram")]
        public static void StopProgram(int processId)
```

Here is the full source code: https://github.com/maifeeulasad/SIGINT-APP/blob/210561ed4e49d89321ed4d82627ac162fbf69c32/SendCtrlC.cs

Here I'm using this library: https://github.com/3F/DllExport. It has the most stars on GitHub and most download NuGet as of my knowledge.

But when I'm creating a small .NET console application to test, and trying to invoke function exported, it's throwing an error saying: **`System.EntryPointNotFoundException: 'Unable to find an entry point named 'StopProgram' in DLL 'SigInt-CtrlC.dll'.'`**

Here is my relavant code:

```
[DllImport("SigInt-CtrlC.dll")]
static extern void StopProgram(int processId);

StopProgram(pid); // <----- the error is being thrown here
```

Here is the reference to the exact `.dll`: https://github.com/maifeeulasad/SIGINT-APP/blob/94ea0d9db757649ba190fd0dca36a65e1a17a784/bin/Release/netstandard2.0/SigInt-CtrlC.dll

Please note

- I've copied the generate `.dll` both is root source folder where all my source code lies and also in the debug folder where the `.exe` build and other `.dll`s being generated.
- I'm also working on the same device.

*So there should be no system difference issue*

*I've tried opening it into dependency walker 2.2, it gives me some error saying that it has some missing deps. Then I read this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36244483/10305444, and stopped debugging the `.dll`*

**You can either give me a fix to to import it properly, or export it.**

Comment: [DllImport("SigInt-CtrlC.dll", ExactSpelling=true)]

Comment: @HansPassant still the same error..

Comment: Maybe just try using another library? This may be just a bug. And file there an issue if selecting another lib works.

Comment: Verify that its being exported correctly using DLL Export Viewer at https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/dll_export_viewer.html

Answer (score 2):

There's a couple things going on. The biggest thing is that `DllExport` isn't required if you are calling managed code from managed code. (C# -> C#). You typically want to use it for unmanaged to managed interop.

We can work through this though.

Second thing, the output in `bin\Release\netstandard2.0\SigInt-CtrlC.dll` is **not** the dll you want to use. This dll doesn't have any exports. You can verify this by using a dev cmd prompt and dumping the export table: `dumpbin /exports SigInt-CtrlC.dll`

```
> dumpbin /exports SigInt-CtrlC.dll
Microsoft (R) COFF/PE Dumper Version 14.36.32502.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.


Dump of file SigInt-CtrlC.dll

File Type: DLL

  Summary

        2000 .reloc
        2000 .rsrc
        2000 .text
```

The files with the exports created from DllExport are in the `bin\Release\<Platform>` folder.

```
> dumpbin /exports x64/SigInt-CtrlC.dll
Microsoft (R) COFF/PE Dumper Version 14.36.32502.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.


Dump of file x64\SigInt-CtrlC.dll

File Type: DLL

  Section contains the following exports for \SigInt-CtrlC.dll

    00000000 characteristics
    6429B342 time date stamp Sun Apr  2 12:54:26 2023
        0.00 version
           1 ordinal base
           1 number of functions
           1 number of names

    ordinal hint RVA      name

          1    0 0000291E StopProgram

  Summary

        2000 .reloc
        2000 .rsrc
        2000 .sdata
        2000 .text
```

Finally, I was unable to get the managed to managed interop to work (unmanaged to managed was fine) unless I had this specific option checked in the .NET DllExport options:

[image: Image showing that the 'Use out IL Assembler' is checked]

Using the correct dll and the corresponding option the DllImport call started working.

Comment: When you say it wouldn't work, what did happen?

Comment: An `SEHException` occurred. I made sure this was not due to mismatched architectures either because I tested x86 from and x64 exe and got the expected `BadFormatException`.

Comment: Did you try different `CallingConvention` for example `CDecl`

Comment: Just tested. CDecl didn't help (turned off 'Use our IL Assembler'). When I turned the option back on, CDecl works.