# How to link dependency DLLs from WinSxS directory

Tags: dll, winsxs, epicor

We're using Epicor 7.4 SP7 for any that's familiar. I have 2 machines, 1 where the program installed without issue, and another where there were 3 DLL registration errors. I've since taken care of 2 of the DLL errors using dependency walker, but for the 3rd error I cannot figure out how to fix it.

This is the machine where the program installed without issue:

[image]

This is the machine that has the 3 missing dependency DLLs:

[image]

So my question is, like the title say, how do I get the 3 missing dependency DLLs from the WinSxS directory to link to the DLL that is having the issue?

I've tried copying the DLL, .res, and .tlb file for SMCBROWSER in SysWOW64 and the folders within WinSxS that contain the dependency DLLs, but it did not work. Dependency Walker still says it's missing the 3 dependent DLLs.

Comment: https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=26347

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dependency Walker: missing dlls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36240215/dependency-walker-missing-dlls)